# Sharing variables through files with webpack

Tags: javascript, variables, webpack

I have 2 js files.
First file:

```
var object1 = {
    foo: 'bar'
}
```

Second file

```
var object2 = {
    foo2: 'bar2'
}
console.log(object1.foo);
```

These 2 files are build with webpack to bundle.js file.
But in this case I have troubles - object1 variable is not defined.

I analyzed code in bundle.js file - webpack create for every file anonymous function - and I understand why I have error.

It's possible do with webpack or not ?

Off course I can use this variable as global variable, but I think - it's not a good idea.

Comment: Use a namespace instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer it's very simple, just use require

```
var object1 = require('./object1.js');
var object2 = {
    foo2: 'bar2'
}
console.log(object1.foo);
```