# Webpack code splitting

Tags: javascript, webpack

Im trying to set up my project with webpack, i've read about code-splitting and i am trying to make two separate bundles, one for the actual application code and the other for libraries and frameworks. So my webpack config looks like this:

```
entry: {
    app: './app/index.js',
    vendor: './app/vendor.js'
},
output: {
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/js')
},

watch: true,

module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
            use: 'css-loader'
        })
    }]
},

plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css'),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'vendor'
    })
]
```

in my vendor.js bundle i have only one line:

```
 import moment from 'moment';
```

And when i try to use it in my app.js file it tells me, that moment is not defined. So, the thing that i don't get, do bundles have common scope or not? If not, then how can i access variables that i've exported in another bundle and if i can't, then what's even the point of having the vendor bundle like described here https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-libraries/ ?

Comment: is `moment js` in node_modules? how do you use `vendor.js` in `index.js`

Comment: yes it is in node_modules, otherwise webpack would've outputted an error while building. I include vendor.js then app.js in my index.html file. As i told, vendor js only have one line with importing moment, and index.js has one line with console.log(moment())

Comment: You need to required vendor.js, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31433772/sharing-variables-through-files-with-webpack

Comment: If you are looking for a solution for Webpack 4+, then maybe [this short walkthrough](https://www.robinwieruch.de/webpack-code-splitting-library) gives you everything you need for Code Splitting your JavaScript library.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bundles do not share a scope. In fact webpack respects the scope of each module, just like Node.js, so you can't use anything from another module unless you import it, even if it's in the same bundle.

You need to import `moment` in every module you're using it. This doesn't mean you include its source code multiple times. Webpack includes the source once, and every import will refer to that.

Code splitting, the `CommonsChunkPlugin` in this case, simply puts the source into the vendor bundle, and every import across the bundles will refer to the vendor bundle. This means that you don't ship the vendor dependencies with your app bundle and therefore the vendor bundle can be cached by the browser. When you publish a new version of your app without changing your vendor bundle, the browser will only need to download the app bundle, as it already has the correct vendor bundle.

---

Let's consider this very short example app:

```
import moment from 'moment';
console.log(moment().format());
```

Without the `CommonsChunkPlugin` the resulting bundles (not uglified) are:

```
vendor.js  470 kB       0  [emitted]  [big]  vendor
   app.js  470 kB       1  [emitted]  [big]  app
```

That's 470 KB, because it contains the entire `moment` source in the bundle and even worse, another bundle that also uses `moment`, contains the entire source as well. The vendor isn't supposed to use it here, but think of another bundle that would need to use it. When you change something in the app, the user would have to download the entire 470 KB again.

With the `CommonsChunkPlugin`:

```
   app.js  504 bytes       0  [emitted]         app
vendor.js     473 kB       1  [emitted]  [big]  vendor
```

Now the app went down to 504 bytes. And when you change the app, the user will only have to download this small bundle (assuming `vendor.js` is already cached). This also means any additional bundle that uses `moment` would also refer to `vendor.js` instead of including the source in the bundle.

The size of `vendor.js` slightly increased, because webpack needs some extra code to handle the imports from another bundle. This also requires the `vendor.js` to be loaded before the `app.js`.

I left out the hashes in the filenames for brevity, but they would be required for cache busting. For more information see [Caching](https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/).

Comment: So, im not really splitting the code architecture-wise, since i need to do all the importing in my index.js file, despite i've already done it in vendor.js?

Comment: And by the way, i've just tried to do the same thing with angular and it seems to work just like i thought it's supposed to work. I've imported angular in vendor.js and it's avaiable in index.js somehow. Why can't this work with moment?

Comment: Every module should be able to be run by itself, relying on a global variable being present is generally problematic, and only legacy modules do that (e.g. jQuery plugins). Some modules might expose something as a global, but that is the same story. See [Shimming](https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/) for more details. Modules are essential in JavaScript and the days of having to expose everything globally are over.

Answer (score 4):

I see the problem, and it's not related with code splitting. There are different ways to achieve this, depending on your specific case:

#### Require `vendor.js` in `index.js`:

*vendor.js*

```
export default moment from 'moment';
```

*index.js*

```
var moment = require('vendor.js');
console.log(moment());
```

#### Using import loaders:

The imports loader allows you to use modules that depend on specific global variables. This is useful for third-party modules that rely on global variables like $ or this being the window object. The imports loader can add the necessary require('whatever') calls, so those modules work with webpack.

```
require("imports-loader?$=moment,angular!./index.js");
```

#### Via plugins:

You can expose momentJS to the windows object via plugins, so you can access from index.js as `window.moment`.

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    "window.moment": "moment"
}),
```

Answer (score 0):

So I had been pulling my hairs for simply importing an object and all its methods from a separate `.js` file to the `app.js` while using `webpack`. As it turned out, all you have to do is....

Lets say you have this `var xys{};` object defined inside `ourjsfile.js`

And you have defined various methods like ..

```
xyz.add = function(){ ... };
```

At the end of the file all you have to do is add..

```
module.exports = xyz;
```

Thats all!!! Now in order to use this object(variable) in `app.js` you have to require it as below...

```
var xyz = require('./ourjsfile');
```

And lo and behold!!! The object is imported. This thing had me pulling my hairs for bit too long for such a simple solution.